# Qt3D: QVector3D::unproject of QPickEvent mouse position yields wrong 3D coordinates

Tags: qt, opengl, 3d, qt3d

I know this question has been asked multiple times but I still can't figure out what is wrong in my code. I have a `QEntity` with a `QObjectPicker` attached to it. What I'm trying to achieve is that the user can move the object in the plane parallel to the near and far plane. But at the moment I'm only trying to project back the mouse coordinates to obtain the world intersection.

A `QPickEvent` already provides the world intersection but I need to compute it myself so that it has the same depth as the first world intersection of when the user pressed the mouse button. This way I can compute the difference vector and move the object by that difference.

To this end I implemented the following procedure (`projectionMatrix` is a projection matrix manually set on the camera and stored in a variable that's why I set it here directly):

```cpp
float distance = pickEvent->distance();
float posY = height() - pickEvent->position().y() - 1.0f;
QVector3D screenCoordinates = QVector3D(pickEvent->position().x(), posY, distance);
QMatrix4x4 modelViewMatrix = camera->viewMatrix() * object->transform()->matrix();
QVector3D mouseIn3D = screenCoordinates.unproject(modelViewMatrix,
                                                  projectionMatrix,
                                                  QRect(0, 0, width(), height()));
```

`object` is the object I'm trying to move. An example of values I obtain are:

- pick distance is `600.787`
- pick event world intersection is `(-72.0421, 27.4382, 697.146)`
- the projection of the screen coordinates `mouseIn3D` is `(168.434, 708.616, 29.4223)`

Obviously this is not correct as the world intersection and the projected mouse coordinates differ a lot. I also tried `0.f` and `1.f` for distance instead of the `600.787` because some people said that's the depth value of the near and far plane but this didn't work either and gave wrong coordinates.

---

On the other hand, when I project the 3D local intersection provided by the `QPickEvent` to the screen, the 2D pixel coordinates are correct:

```cpp
QVector3D pointOnModel = pickEvent->localIntersection();
QVector3D projected = pointOnModel.project(modelViewMatrix,
                                           projectionMatrix,
                                           QRect(0, 0, width(), height()));
qDebug() << "x y" << pickEvent->position().x() << height() - pickEvent->position().y();
qDebug() << "projected" << projected;
```

This yields

```
x y 949 1118
projected QVector3D(949, 1118, 0.90164)
```

---

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use the camera->viewMatrix() only for unprojecting screen coordinates, not the modelViewMatrix.

Comment: This yields e.g. this vector: `QVector3D(0.0165976, -0.0064082, -0.175081)`, so not correct either. I understand why I shouldn't use the `modelViewMatrix` but the result was closer in this case. Any idea why this could be the case?

Comment: Well, your comment pointed me towards the right direction. The mistake was multiplying by the model matrix and using the distance to the camera instead of depth.

Comment: I just started with another comment exactly on the depth issue  :). Glad it helped.